# Reference Closed Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to load data into an array from an external workbook into an array to run a `For` loop and am getting:

> Error 1004 C:filepath/.../.../.xlsx cannot be found, check the spelling of the file name and verify the location is correct.

I made sure the spelling is correct, and I made sure path was correct. The file usually resides on a network drive, so I moved it to my desktop to be certain.

Could Bitlocker or a security suite interfere?

```
 'Error happens on second line
 TargetPath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ldgt1.xlsx"
 Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TargetPath)
 Set SourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook


 'This is where I am loading the array with a for loop
 ArraySize = WorksheetFunction.CountA(TargetWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns(1))
 ReDim Array(ArraySize)
     For i = 1 To ArraySize
         numbers(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
     Next i
```

Comment: What happens if you do `MsgBox Dir("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ldgt1.xlsx")`

Comment: Also note: when using the network drive path, it may be necessary to use the full UNC path instead of the local mapped drive letter.

Comment: Right-click on the file and check its properties, or open it in Excel and run `? ActiveWorkbook.Path` in the Immediate pane. It's possible it isn't where you think it is.

Comment: also note the *possible* typographical errors in filename where the lower-case letter `"l"` looks very similar to the digit `"1"`.

Comment: Also, make sure your `Worksheets(1)` is what you want to use, and not `Sheets("Sheet1")` as they can be different.  (`Worksheets(1)` refers to the first spreadsheet in the sheets array, `Sheets("Sheet1")` refers to the sheet actually called "Sheet1"). Edit: Ah, nevermind - that would come in to play at your `ArraySize`, not setting the path...

Comment: @Davesexcel he did `thisworkbook` not `activeworkbook`

Comment: Do you have "hide extensions for known file types" turned on in Windows Explorer?  Is it possible this file is actually called `ldgt1.xlsx.xlsx`  ? P.S.  I hate that setting...

Comment: Duh! It was a typo on my end... It is set to     `TargetPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\ldWgt.xlsx"`

Comment: @LucasCrostarosa: So is the question solved? Or was that a response to a comment?